# Service Pack Installation Backup Procedures

Tags: backup, restore, service-pack

I have two farms . One is the staging farm and the other is the production farm. All MOSS 2007  Content Deployment is configured from stage to production environment

We have 10 web applications running on this environment. We have to do a Service Pack installation on both the farms.

What is the best backup procedures for this scenario and the restore options incase of a failure in upgradation or a failover plan in case of a failure

Answer (score 1):

Backup all your Config and Content databases, and your servers, before doing the update.  If your servers are VMs, snapshot them before the update.  You'll need to have a maintenance window to do the update.  Depending on the size of your content, you may need a weekend.

You then have a restore point you can go back to.

Microsoft's Service Pack installation documents (find them on the [Sharepoint Products and Technologies Update Resource Centre](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839)) go into some detail about how to backup, and other measures to reduce risk.  Read them in depth.

Comment: Can you share the documents

Comment: Microsoft share them on their site.  They will have the most up to date ones that match the service pack you are installing.  Linked in the document above - although you could have Googled it in less time it took me to Google it and update the post...